# How would I make a .bat script to take info from one command output, execute commands for each output, to create a file path?

Tags: batch-file

So, what I'm going for, is to execute `net user` and have only the accounts listed to a .txt file. (This I've done, but the final line "command completed successfully." still outputs.) From there, take each account and check if it's active. (`net user [account] | findstr /C:"Account active"`). Then make .txt file of those that are. Then simply copy to clipboard the filepath C:\Users(The user found)\AppData\Roaming. If there is a way around making the .txt files that would be great, but I could just end the script by deleting them. The part I'm currently stuck on is getting the 'for' command to collect tokens from all the lines of text not just the last one (and output them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "skip=4 delims=" %%a in ('net user^|find /v "Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt"') do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    net user %%b | findstr /rc:"Konto aktiv.*Ja" >nul && >>ActiveAccounts.txt echo %%b
  )
)
```

The output of `net user` is language-dependent. Change the search strings to your language.

The outer `for /f` loop processes the output of the `net user` command (minus the "Command successful" line, filtered by `find`), skipping the Header. The inner `for` disassembles the line into words (users) and executes the `net user <username>` command. `Findstr` filters for the `Account active`...`Yes` line and if successful (`&&`), prints the username.

Your clipboard request doesn't make sense, as there may be more than one active account. (If you are positive, there is just one active user, you can use the [clip](https://ss64.com/nt/clip.html) command to `echo` something to the clipboard)

Comment: I changed the skip= to 4, because it was skipping the first line of accounts, but other than that it worked perfectly, thank you!